# CommonJS for OOP in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, commonjs

Is it good practice to write *all* javascript "classes" as CommonJS modules within an Appcelerator Titanium Mobile app instead of using functions / object notation to create a new "class" (or how you call them in javascript anyway)?

```
var module = require('lib/module');
```

instead of

```
var object = new MyClass();
```

Are there any disadvantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe it is completely supported on all platforms and all versions of the SDK at this time.

See this issue in QA Forum

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/125373/common-js-modules---no-build-on-device

and

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/124473/commonjs-modules---typeerror-in-production#answer-218739